# Is a Windows 10 device bricked when you don't remember the password and a wrong PIN has been entered three times?

Tags: windows-10, login, password-recovery, pin

I was given an HP stream tablet some months ago as a gift and upgraded it to Windows 10 when it came out.

The friend who gave it to me quickly set it to PIN and I forgot the password as I never used it again. The PIN was just `1234` as neither the tablet nor anything of it was of any value.

Somewhere in the last 24 hours either there were phantom taps on the login screen while the device was in my luggage, or somebody tried to play with the device when I was not around. It now tells me there were three wrong PIN attempts.

I can switch between PIN login and password login but I don't remember the password. I'm guessing I'll only get three attempts at that too.

Is the device bricked or is there a password recovery strategy?

(I have Google but keep hitting questions about Windows Phone or PIN locket without forgetting the password.)

Comment: I've never used Windows 10, but I believe if you've attached your Microsoft Live account to your PC login, you can go to live.com to reset your computer's password if it's connected to the internet. Windows 10 might require a Live account by default. Here's this article: http://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/

Comment: I think it only allows you to set a pin if you have it connected to your ms account

Comment: I seem to recall adding it to my Live Account at some point after the upgrade to Win 10. Will try and let you all here know how it went.

Comment: @hippietrail yes, you added your MS account.. I am sure as I was with you when you did it. Reset it using MS account password..

Comment: I've probably also forgotten my MS account password. I almost never use it.

Comment: @hippietrail something else is bricked then :D